# Wordpress Gallery, how to dynamically update a custom select box on attachment upload

Tags: wordpress

I've added a select box audio option to the default gallery settings. Here's what I added to the functions.php file:

```
    <?php
      function add_custom_gallery_settings() {

        global $post;
        $attached_audio = get_attached_media( 'audio', $post->ID );

    ?>
    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-custom-gallery-settings">
      <label class="setting">
       <span><?php _e('Audio'); ?></span>
       <select data-setting="audio">
        <option value="">No Audio</option>
       <?php foreach($attached_audio as $a): ?>
          <option value="<?php esc_attr_e($a->ID); ?>">
              <?php echo $a->post_name; ?>
          </option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
       </select>
      </label>
    </script>
    <script>

      jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({

         render: function() {

           wp.media.view.Settings.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);

           this.$el.append(wp.media.template('custom-gallery-settings'));

           wp.media.gallery.defaults.audio = null;

           this.update.apply( this, ['audio'] );

           return this;
         }

       });

     });

    </script>
    <?php }

      add_action('print_media_templates', 'add_custom_gallery_settings');

    ?>
```

As you see, select box populates with audio attachments uploaded to the post. Because I generate those templates on print_media_templates hook, any audio files uploaded to the post, won't show up until I update/save the post and/or reload the page. Question is, what would be a good way to dynamically update those options when an audio attachment is uploaded?